# Unable to authorize by BFF in Blazor WebAssembly with Duende.IdentityServer in HTTP scheme, not HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, httpcookie, duende-identity-server

I have two sample projects, one for **Duende Identity Server** and another for **Blazor WebAssembly** project, they are both writen by .NET 7 and we are using latest release of Duende Identity server with **BFF(Backend For Frontend)** protocol.

---

***The problem:***

When we use **HTTPS** for authority and all addresses for both client and server there is no problem! and we can successfully authenticate and authorize in Blazor Client app.

But we have problem when using **HTTP**:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

I know that we have to use HTTPS in production, but now we are in development and we should have been able to do it in development.

---

***Public repository:***

You can find the projects in **public repository**:
**https://github.com/miladashrafi/binande**

---

***Steps to reproduce the problem:***

Just clone the repository and run both following projects:

```
Binande.Identity
Binande.Admin.Server
```

---

***Steps to see that there is no problem in HTTPS mode:***

1- Change urls from HTTP to HTTPS in both projects **launchSettings.json**

*Binande.Admin.Server:*

```json
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5002"
```

*Binande.Identity:*

```json
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
```

2- Change urls of **interactive.confidential** client in **IdentityServerConfig.cs**:

*Binande.Identity:*

```cs
RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002" },
```

3- Change the Authority url of **Program.cs** in Binande.Identity project:

```cs
options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
```

**Now it's working fine!**

---

***Question:***

The question is: how to have this in **HTTP mode** instead of HTTPS in development environment?

---

***Note:***

We have `options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;` and `options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;` and `options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;` in cookie policies and configuration.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, your cookie name does not seem to meet its restrictions, after changing it can be authenticated normally.

Chang your cookie name:

```
options.Cookie.Name = "Host-blazor";
```

Test Result:
[image]
It has some restrictions on `__Host-` and `__Secure-` prefixed names. For more details, you can check the `Cookie prefixes` section in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies).

Comment: Thank you @Chen
You are prefect, 